# Is there a flower which can handle temperatures up to 40 Celsius?

Tags: flowers, desert

The temperature in my country can go around 40 degrees Celsius in summer.

So I wanted to know what are the flowers I could plant that can handle temperatures such as this?

Comment: What are your nighttime temperatures? How long do the high temperatures last? Which country? Do you mean what can you transplant/seed then, or what can flower in those temperatures? We get roses blooming in those temperatures. Sunflowers, too. Other stuff. Amaranth should.

Comment: Well I'm in the UAE, the night time temperatures are between the 20-30s Celsius and the high temperatures last from about 10 in the morning to 2-3 afternoon. For germination I can put them inside the house with air conditioning at 18-21 Celsius. So I wanted to know what can germinate inside the house, and what can germinate outside and survive, and what can survive outside after germinating inside. Sorry for asking too much and thank you very much for your care :)

Comment: I am thinking of a [Desert Rose](https://worldofsucculents.com/how-to-grow-and-care-for-desert-rose/). I am not sure what max temperatures it can handle, but I am sure it can handle heat and a lot of sun light.

Comment: Are cactus and succulents available in UAE? There are a number of nice succulent trees (Adenium) from Saudi Arabia and Yemen as well as east Africa.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least a couple of sites ([1](https://gardenerdy.com/arabian-desert-plants), [2](https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/native-plants-of-saudi-arabia.html)) that list plants native to the Arabian Peninsula. I bet others from the Sonoran or Saharan Deserts could also survive, for example some Agaves.